# Communicate with parent component without using state/props

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need a parent component to know when it's child components have changed from collapsed to expanded and viceversa.

I don't want to keep that in the app state (Redux). I can't move the logic up to the parent component.

My components are:

- I have component C which is an item that can be expanded/collapsed.
- Then I have Component B which is a wrapper for component C in a specific case (gives it the draggable behaviour).
- And finally component A which lists components C in a loop. A, sometimes wraps Cs in B, and sometimes not (when items shouldnt be draggable).

I need B to know C is expanded, so that it isn't draggable while expanded.

I can't put the expanded/collapsed logic in B, because C should always be collapsible/expandable independently of if draggable.

Is there any simple way to accomplish this without needing to have the expand/collapse state of each item in the app state?

I have read about https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/context.html but seems still in experimental phase...

Comment: Can you explain better why you don't want to "keep that in the app state"? And why you need a Component B? You could do conditional rendering with props without an extra component.

Comment: You might got the wrong idea about React if you don't want to use state: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/interactivity-and-dynamic-uis.html#components-are-just-state-machines

Comment: by app state I mean Redux. I am using redux to keep the state of the whole app, but keeping the expanded/collapsed state can be and should be done at the component level, which is what I'm doing now. That's why I need to somehow send this info to its parent component

Comment: I need a component B because all the logic for the drag n drop is quite complex. Also, component B wraps A with other stuff, that A doesn't always need. I have two view modes, imagine a grid view and a list view, both have the same data (component C) but both have several differences (component B)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep the expanded state inside the C component and update the draggable state of the B component with a callback passed with the props of the C component.
In this way both components keep their own state, no need to add the state on the A component or in you App state (the Redux one).

**Here is an example**: https://jsfiddle.net/snahedis/69z2wepo/28567/

```
var sampleList = [{id: 1, draggable: true},{id: 2, draggable: false}];

var Acomponent = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        {sampleList.map(function(component) {
          if (component.draggable) {
            return <Bcomponent key={component.id} />;
          } else {
            return <Ccomponent key={component.id} />;
          }
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
});

var Bcomponent = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
        draggable: true
    }
  },
  hasBeenToggled: function() {
    this.setState({
        draggable: !this.state.draggable
    });
  },
  render: function() {
    return <Ccomponent draggable={this.state.draggable} toggleExpandableCallback={this.hasBeenToggled} />;
  }
});

var Ccomponent = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
        expanded: false
    }
  },
  toggleExpandable: function() {
    this.setState({
        expanded: !this.state.expanded
    });

    if (typeof this.props.toggleExpandableCallback === "function") {
        this.props.toggleExpandableCallback();
    }
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>I'm the C component and my expanded state is : {this.state.expanded.toString()}</div>
        <div>{(this.props.draggable) ? "oh, and I'm draggable !" : "and I'm saddly not draggable"}</div>
        <button onClick={this.toggleExpandable}>Change expandable state</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <Acomponent />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Comment: yep, this is how I ended up doing it, thanks for the answer though :)

Answer (score 0):

A few ideas:

1) You can ALWAYS render B (A renders B's, each which wraps a C), but just disable the draggable behavior in B when it shouldn't be draggable (pass it in something like a `isDraggable` to B). Then, C's collapsible state can be stored in B, and passed a prop to C, as B will always be there.

2) You can move all the state to A (not sure if this is what you mean by "app state")

It's hard to suggest without knowing more context. But in cases like this, there's almost a better way to break up your components / app state so that it doesn't feel "wrong."

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I considered having A to always render B, but it's not a very nice solution in this case. A has the state to choose between viewmode, viewmode basically means looping printing C or B(C). B adds several features to C, not only draggable, but also DOM elements around it and it wouldn't really work out ;( To have the expanded/collapsed info in A, i'd need some kind of array to map all the items which doesn't make sense. In that case it would make more sense to have it in the app state, by app state I mean Redux. I'll give a second thought to my component structure, thanks!